# How auto.arima works?

Tags: r, arima

I found `auto.arima()` function in `forecast` packages.
As far I have understand how it works, It should find the best model for the data, my question is: Is it possible to understand if the variance is not constant during all the period(timeseries) using that function? I mean...
If it fit a model it should means that the variance is homoscedastics because i set `stationary=TRUE`

Let me know, thank you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
?auto.arima
```

> Returns best ARIMA model according to either AIC, AICc or BIC value.
>   The function conducts a search over possible model within the order
>   constraints provided.

This means it tries all the possible parameters (within the constraints provided) and returns the model with the lowest AIC, AICc or BIC.

For more information, you can [read the article referenced](http://www.jstatsoft.org/v27/i03/paper) in `?auto.arima`.